# Can liferay portlets listen to Database events?

Tags: java, database, liferay, cluster-computing

**My current setup :**

- Multiple nodes share the same database updating the values.
- The cache is NOT shared among them

**Requirement :**

- The liferay cache needs to be updated when any one node does a DB update.

**Question**

- Is there a way portlets can listen to my database and update its cache .
- Is cache independency a correct approach ? (I dont have control over this decision)
- If we do proper clustering, can we shut down a node independent of the other. Will liferay handle this automatically ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Not every DBMS supports client notifications. Btw: Liferay supports a distributed cache through EHCache. Search the Liferay Wiki there are several articles on that.

Comment: We are using ORACLE for the production system. However i would like to test it in my local MYSQL as well.

Comment: **Never** use a different DBMS for development and production. Especially if it's so limited as MySQL. Oracle *does* support client notifications, MySQL does not.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you think having an independent cache can cause data integrity problems? Or will liferay handle it automatically ? Also can you give more details on client notifications and is there any integration directly in liferay ?

Comment: For the notification see here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#CACHJFCC

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check it out !

Answer (score 0):

I would cluster Liferay and enable propagation of cache invalidation. Then when something changes the data would be automatically  updated.

If you by cache independency mean that the cache is not replicated then I would say yes. Replication is costly and propagation of cache invalidation should suffice.

If you have clustering you have to have node balancing in front of Liferay (apache ...). Then when you kill one Liferay the balancer should detect it and ignore the killed node until it goes up again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I am implementing the same in cluster now :)